# Can we debug iphone app in window

Tags: ios, debugging, codenameone

I have developed simple app for ios using codenameone. I do not have
 mac book  I want to debug the app so how  can I debug the app in
 window laptop?

Comment: You can debug on the simulator, for on device debugging you will need Mac OS as you would need to run xcode to debug on the device as explained here: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html We would like to add "On Device Debugging" that will work on all OS's and it's something that is within our roadmap.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog the "On iOS Device Debugging" for Windows users is still in your roadmap? Have you planned a release date?

Comment: No. This just keeps getting further away instead of closer. We need more developers to accomplish everything we want to do and for that we need more users...

Comment: @ShaiAlmog it's a pity, it would be a great functionality.

Comment: We need more enterprise subscribers so we can fund long term efforts like this. This requires about 6 man months worth of work to get working and we can't spare an engineer for such a long haul effort.

Answer (score 1):

codenameone has its own plugin for Netbeans IDE. You can install Netbeans IDE in windows and then add codenameone plugin to that. Then connect your IDE with your code in cloud and you can start working on that.

For cross platforms like codenameone you dont need to have Mac machines for development.

For more information you can visit the following link

[INFO ABOUT CODENAMEONE](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/)

Hope this helps...